# How to upload certificate using sdb in command line in tizen

Tags: cmd, certificate, tizen, xml-signature, tizen-sdb

I want to install a tizen app in a remote location. I want to upload the certificate using command line. What is the equivalent command for "Permit to install applications" in context menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Tizen device are you working on ?

you need to upload the signature xml file into :

```
sdb push *.xml /home/developer
```

You can also try CLI SDK and share feedback on tizen wiki

Comment: Hi, I've got an error `/home/developer': Permission denied while trying this. Do you know any workaround? (I have turn on developer mode on TV)